# Adding custom JQuery as Directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying my hand at Angular for the first time and I still find it somewhat confusing.

In my previous project (which was built on Rails and Used coffeescript as JS) my solution to add and remove a class to my navbar looked like this:

```
$ ->
  #caches a jQuery object containing the header element
  header = $('#flipping-navbar')
  $(window).scroll ->
    scroll = $(window).scrollTop()
    if scroll >= 600
      header.removeClass('blue-navbar').addClass 'white-navbar'
    else
      header.removeClass('white-navbar').addClass 'blue-navbar'
    return
  return
```

From what I can figure out, it seems like I should be adding this functionality as a Directive in my Angular app, but I'm not quite sure how to do this. I've started like this (but now I'm completely confused):

```
angular.module('webFrontendApp.directives', []);
.directive("landing-scroll", function ($window) {
    angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {

    });
});
```

Thanks for the help.

**UPDATE**

In my directive file I now have (as per answer below):

```
angular.module('webFrontendApp.directives', [])
.directive("scroll", function ($window) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
             if (this.pageYOffset >= 100) {
                 scope.boolChangeClass = true;
                 console.log('Scrolled below header.');
             } else {
                 scope.boolChangeClass = false;
                 console.log('Header is in view.');
             }
            scope.$apply();
        });
    };
});
```

And in my view:

```
<nav class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" scroll ng-class="{min:boolChangeClass}">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-target = "#collapse-menu" data-toggle = "collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="/" class = "navbar-brand">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id = "collapse-menu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="page-scroll">
          <a href="#">Reserve my store</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS looks like this:

```
nav{
    height: 100px;
    background-color: grey !important;
}

// section {
//     height: 900px;
//     background-color: lightgrey;
// }

.min nav {
    background-color: pink !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going the right way. Like in the example:

```js
app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive("scroll", function ($window) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
             if (this.pageYOffset >= 100) {
                 scope.boolChangeClass = true;
                 console.log('Scrolled below header.');
             } else {
                 scope.boolChangeClass = false;
                 console.log('Header is in view.');
             }
            scope.$apply();
        });
    };
});
```

```css
#page {
    height: 1000px;
}

header {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: grey;
}

section {
    height: 900px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

.min section {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" scroll id="page" ng-class="{min:boolChangeClass}">

    <header></header>
    <section></section>
    
</div>
```

Comment: I mean you just need to insert the directive in the navbar html element

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have tried your solution, but can't get it working yet. When I add this code to my directive my terminal produces the warnings that 'attrs' and 'element' are defined but never used. I have updated my question to show exactly what I'm doing.